# Matlab: subtract every value in a row from every other, for every row

Tags: matlab, subtraction

I have data like this: [...

0...0...0...0
6...0...0...0
8...5...2...0
9...8...3...1
0...0...0...0

Within each row I would like to subtract every value individually from every other in that row. So that I get a new matrix which shows all the differences like this: [...

null
0
3...6...3
1...6...8...5...7...2
null

I hope you see what I mean. I don't want to subtract 0 from anything (O is null for me-if you have a way to replace 0 with null thats fine). Or at least, if this has to be done, I want those results to be discarded. But I DO want there to be some placeholder when a row is entirely made of 0s.

The ordering of the resulting subtractions doesn't matter, except that the row order overall should be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PDIST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist.html) to calculate the distances:

```
data =[0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0
8 5 2 0
9 8 3 1
0 0 0 0];
nRows = size(data,1);

%# for speed, preassign 'out'
out = cell(nRows,1);

for r = 1:nRows
   pts = data(r,data(r,:)>0); %# this assumes valid entries are >0
   switch length(pts),
   case 0,
      out{r} = []; %# empty for 'null'
   case 1, 
      out{r}=0; %# zero if only one valid number
   otherwise
      out{r}=pdist(pts'); %'# calculate all differences
   end
end

%# You access elements of a cell array with curly brackets
>> out{3}
ans =
     3     6     3
```

Comment: @jonas. once again a great answer. What is name of the output matrix in that?

Comment: @Tom: I called it `out`, for lack of creativity.

Comment: @jonas. But in this case, it seems I am unable to display them all at once by writing 'out' or xlswrite('data.xls',out)?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, because `out` is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br1xnp2-1), which I use to store arrays of variable length.

Comment: @Jonas. Yes I see. So then how will I go on to operate on all of the 'out' rows at once? Can I create a new matrix with NaN or something in the null columns??

Comment: @Tom: What do you want to do? In many cases, [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) can be useful. Note that if you have N non-zeros in a row, you get N(N-1)/2 differences, so if you want to transform `out` into a full array, it might get rather large.

Comment: @jonas. It's because I then need to convert all my values into new values (each individually from a look-up table) and then add them up per row. I don't mind if the full array is large, because my initial array is never more than 13 columns now.

Comment: @Tom: assuming the LUT allows direct indexing, you can convert the values like this: `convertedSum = cellfun(@(x)sum(LUT(x)),out)`. For every element in the cell array (i.e. every row), this will read the values from the look-up table `LUT`, and sum the result. Note that if `LUT` is an array and not a function, you'll need to do something about the cell elements containing 0, since you can't index with 0 unless they're logical 0's. Note that also, you could perform the looking-up and summing directly, without needing to produce the cell array.